kwin script to send KeyEvent
I'm trying to make a kwin script that sends a keystroke to a window, but I'm not sure this function is even available.
Does anyone know how to fill the blanks?
const clients = workspace.windowList();

for (let i = 0; i < clients.length; i++) {
  clients[i].sendKeyEvent(...);
}


Have you considered using xdotool? Note that if the window is not focused, it may just ignore the event.

Unfortunately I'm using Wayland, I've considered ydotool, but couldn't make it work. However, I would prefer to do it all in kwin if possible.
